# Sum of all processes' real memory not equal to used memory?

Tags: macos, memory

I wonder why the sum of all processes' real memory listed in `Activity Monitor` is not equal to (MUCH less than) the used memory?

Comment: Used memory is the sum of Wired + Active + Inactive. I think (but am not certain) that the sum of the real memory would be equal to Active + Inactive.

Comment: That's strange, on my mac about 1.5gb of ram is unaccounted for lol